# Multiple upload give me error : Could not overwrite file

Tags: document-library

I am using SP 2010. I have a document library. I try to use the multiple upload dialog from SharePoint. I got an error

> Could not overwrite file.

Like you see in the print screen below I have checked "Add as a new version to existing files". Why didn't it overwrite?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried uploading just one of the files? The error message may be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the document needs to be checked out first before you can upload a new version.
So you have two options:

- Turn off that documents need to be checked out before editing
- Check out the document first
  [check this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/760acdd9-bb83-454f-b460-dd0cac07eb79/upload-multiple-documents-could-not-overwrite?forum=sharepointadminprevious)